# Defining global variable SOAPpy Server

Tags: python, soap

I want to create a SOAP Service, on the server side I want to create and manipulate objects/variables, exposing diferente methods: Create object, manipulate, deletec, etc.

Porblem is, I dont know how/where to declare a global variable in the server code, in order to keep the reference to object previously created and be able manipulate

The simple SOAPpy server code is this:

```
import SOAPpy
myobject
def create():
    myobject = Create()
def manipulate():
    myobject.op1()
server = SOAPpy.SOAPServer(("localhost", 8080))
server.registerFunction(hello)
server.serve_forever()
```

When I try to execute this code, I receive an error saying myobject is not declared..

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just 'declare' variable without assigning it a value. Python is dynamically typed, so it deduces type on assigment and binds name to object of that type. You should then assign in second line like:

```
myobject = None
```

or even remove this line and return value from create():

```
def create():
    return Create()

myobject = create() # somewhere where you need it
```